# Evaluating series (such as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2(1.05)^{-n}$)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am currently studying for the actuarial exam FM. I have been working on problems involving duration and convexity of perpetuities. I was in the middle of a problem, and got stuck on trying to evaluate this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2(1.05)^{-n}$$

On my upcoming exam, I am only allowed to use a TI-30XS Multiview calculator, which has most functions (log, exponential, trignometric, etc), but does not do summation. Normally, I would plug something like this into my TI-84 calcultor and find the partial sum till 100, 1,000, 10,000, etc  and try to see if the series converges. Doing this gives me $17,220$ as the value, which wolframalpha confirms is correct.

I've also had this issue with this series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1.05)^{n}(1.10)^{-n}(n)$$ (which wolframalpha confirms is equal to 462).

Can I evaluate these types of series without using an advanced calculator? If so, how?
Note, the solutions given for both of these problems found ways to sidestep these sums, but I am curious about if they can be evaluated directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking at a sum of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 \varrho^n,$$ where, in your case $\varrho=\frac1{1.05}$. Such a series always converges when $\varrho\in]-1,1[$, which is true in your case. It can be evaluated explicitly using summation by parts twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n, |x|<1 $$
and then
$$ \int_0^x\frac{f(t)}{t}dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}. $$
So
$$ f(x)=x\bigg(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\bigg)'=\cdots. $$
So
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2(1.05)^{-n}=f(\frac{1}{1.05})=\cdots.$$

Comment: Good one (but very well-known). I'll add a discrete analogue soon.

Comment: Switching of sum and integral is justified using Fubini, I assume?

Comment: @xpaul Thanks for the answer. I just went through all the steps you outlined and came up with 17,220! I would have never have thought about taking the derivative of the $nx^n$ series. Does this method require having $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ memorized?

Comment: You don't need to memorize. Take derivative for $\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and then you will get it.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, you can use M-test.

Comment: @xpaul Oh, I see now. I like this method:)

Comment: @xpaul I am not sure if I follow: Weierstrass M-test guarantees convergence but not that two limits can be exchanged.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Use M-test in $|x|\le r<1$ for uniformly convergence of $\sum f_n(x)$ and $\sum f'_n(x)$. See https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131bh.1.03s/week45.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a sum of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 \varrho^n,$$ where, in your case $\varrho=\frac1{1.05}$. Such a series always converges when $\varrho\in]-1,1[$, which is true in your case. It can be evaluated explicitly using summation by parts twice.

*Lemma (Summation by parts).* Let $N\in\mathbb N$ and let $a_1,\dots, a_N,b_1,\dots,b_N\in\mathbb R$. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k b_k = A_N b_N + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})$$ where $$A_k \overset{\text{Def.}}=a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_k.$$

*Proof.* Left as an exercise. (*Hint:* Use induction over $N$.)

In our case: Let $N\in\mathbb N$. Let $a_n=\rho^n$ and $b_n=n^2$. We compute for $\rho\neq 1$ $$A_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \rho^n = \frac{\rho(\rho^k-1)}{\rho-1}.$$ Therefore, by the above Lemma,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \rho^n n^2 = \frac{\rho(\rho^N-1)}{\rho-1} N^2+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{\rho(\rho^n-1)}{\rho-1}(-2n-1).$$

Now use summation by parts again for the $n\rho^n$ part and you will get a geometric series. So you can explicitly calculate all the partial sums (and their limit) with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Maximilian. I have actually never heard of summation by parts until reading about it in your answer. I follow what you are saying but at the end when you substitute into the summation by parts formula you imply that $A_{N}b_{N}=\frac{\rho(\rho^N-1)}{\rho-1}$, but isn't $A_{N}b_{N}=p^{n}n^{2}$ (the nth term)?